# Script tag source defaults to URL over path

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I'm trying to make a chat application using socket.io and Node.JS. In my html file called index.html, I am trying to use a script tag to point to a script file called bundle.js that contains a browserified set of variables and functions.

The problem is, despite referencing the proper path in my src attribute, the tag seems to include a bundle.js within my localhost:3000.

Oddly enough, when viewing this bundle.js with developer tools, the content seems to be identical to that of my index.html file. This creates a syntax error as the JavaScript file contains html syntax from my html file. Any ideas why this might be?

```
<script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is how the script tag appears in my html file.

[image]

This is a link to a screenshot of my developer tools (New here so not enough rep to post the actual pic)

Comment: bundle.js is HTML. Check your configuration with webpack, it seems you've broken something.

Comment: @tanaydin that is what the OP is saying himself too. But he doesn't know how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

As we can see bundle.js is open in developer tools is Html code, not js that's why error is shown in first line, or there is something wrong in webpack configuration.

Comment: Right. My actual bundle.js file contains JavaScript code but as I mentioned a bundle.js containing the code from my index.html file is being generated. I'm not sure why this is. How would one go about checking the webpack configuration?